# building portmidi

Tags: c, build, static-libraries, midi

I've been tring to build portmidi on OSX 10.8.2
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/portmedia/wiki/Installing%20portmidi%20on%20Mac

Anyway, the README tells me to first use the command:

```
 make -f pm_mac/Makefile.osx
```

but bash returns the following error message:

```
 [~/Desktop/portmedia/portmidi]
 DanMoore -> make -f pm_mac/Makefile.osx
 rm -f CMakeCache.txt
 mkdir -p Release
 cd Release; cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.2.1
 -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 4.0.0
 -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot
 -- Checking whether C compiler has -isysroot - yes
 -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag
 -- Checking whether C compiler supports OSX deployment target flag - yes
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
 -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
 -- SYSROOT: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
 -- DEFAULT_DEBUG_FLAGS not nil: -g
 -- SYSROOT: /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk
 -- Configuring done
 -- Generating done
 -- Build files have been written to: /Users/DanMoore/Desktop/portmedia/portmidi/Release
 cd Release; make
 Scanning dependencies of target pmjni
 [  3%] Building C object pm_common/CMakeFiles/pmjni.dir/__/pm_mac/pmmacosxcm.c.o
 llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/powerpc-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
 lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/y4/p_kjk8692z73xy4nhwx6h_100000gn/T//cc73yejt.out
 make[3]: *** [pm_common/CMakeFiles/pmjni.dir/__/pm_mac/pmmacosxcm.c.o] Error 255
 make[2]: *** [pm_common/CMakeFiles/pmjni.dir/all] Error 2
 make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
 make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I wasn't expecting an easy build, but these errors look foreign to me.
Can anyone explain whats going on??

I'm trying to render a library file for simple C programs. (.a or .la)

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes a look!!

Comment: If there's `configure` script hiding in there somewhere, try calling it `./configure --disable-mac-universal`.

Comment: nope, there isn't one. I might have to edit the Makefile itself? Thanks

Comment: I had similar issues trying build PortAudio (similar setup as PortMidi), and I gave up.   I ended up building an XCode project with the individual sources (using the makefile as a reference for what I needed).   This wasn't a quick solution, but it did work, and it also allowed me to control compiler/target/optimization settings more easily using XCode.